# BED WARS code answer please leave a comment

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How to join bed wars??? please let me know I am trying to play bed wars but not working

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly isn't working? The more detail you give us, the easier it will be for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to join bedwars on Hypixel, you need to go to multiplayer, add server then type in mc.hypixel.net in the box titled server adress, then press done, the server will be on your server list now and you can double click to play. Once you are on hypixel, right click the compass in your hand and then click the bed in the menu you can then click one of the npc's in the bedwars lobby to join a game.